# How to match sub-string in arrays of strings in F#

Tags: arrays, string, machine-learning, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to learn Machine learning. I am new to F#.
For the given dataset, Let say I have 2 string arrays.

```
let labels = [|"cat"; "dog"; "horse"|]
let scan_data = [|"cat\1.jpg"; "cat\2.jpg"; "dog\1.jpg"; "dog\2.jpg"; "dog\3.jpg"; "horse\1.jpg"; "horse\2.jpg"; "horse\3.jpg"; "horse\4.jpg"; "horse\5.jpg"|]
```

As you must have guessed, there are 3 labels (are kind of folders) which contains training image data (total 10). I want to create using above 2 arrays, a array like this :

```
let data_labels = [|                //val data_labels : int [] []
                      [|1; 0; 0|];  //since 0th scan_data item represent "cat"
                      [|1; 0; 0|];
                      [|0; 1; 0|];  //since 2nd scan_data item represent "dog"
                      [|0; 1; 0|];
                      [|0; 1; 0|];
                      [|0; 0; 1|];  //since 5th scan_data item represent "horse"
                      [|0; 0; 1|];
                      [|0; 0; 1|];
                      [|0; 0; 1|];
                      [|0; 0; 1|];  
                  |]
```

So whenever the sub-string (from "labels") match is found in "scan_data" item there should be an array representing match as "1" and rest no match as "0".
Any thoughts on how to achieve this in F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let helper (str1:string) str2 = if str1.Contains(str2) then 1 else 0
let t = scan_data |> Array.map (fun item -> labels |> Array.map (helper item) )
```

Comment: Thanks @boran. Worked like charm.

Comment: still trying to understand how lambda function's output would be an array of 3 items ?

Comment: @sanjog47 - The output of the lambda would be an array of 3 items because it does `labels |> Array.map (something)`, and `Array.map` always returns an array of the same size as its input array. Since `labels` is an array of 3 items, the result of `labels |> Array.map (something)` would also be an array of 3 items. Notice that I've written `(something)` instead of `(helper item)`, because it doesn't matter what the "something" is. Any time you call `Array.map`, the output array will be the same size as the input array, but with different contents.

Comment: Got it, helper convert string to int, and Array.map in lambda function convert all the three string items to int either 1 or 0. F# - such a impressive language.  :-)

Comment: thanks @rmunn, for summing that up. That's really helpful.

Comment: @sanjog47 - Exactly. Actually, ALL functional programming languages are impressive like that, not just F#. You get to write small functions, then fit them together like Legos into larger building blocks, then fit the larger blocks into a complete program. It's the best programming technique I've ever found. Also, BTW, if you haven't read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ yet, I highly recommend that site: there's a lot more techniques like this in F#, and that site is a great place to learn them.